# Can access paths externally using react router on top of a asp.net project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a asp.net project that runs on IIS, and I've got a page that renders the React SPA. When navigating from inside the app, then the react router seems to do the work and I'm routed to the right page. The problem hits when I either refresh the current page or try to access a page by typing the url. I've done a lot of searching, but the solutions that other people have gotten don't seem to work for me.
I've tried to add a React Controller:

```
public class ReactController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return this.View("React");
        }
    }
```

and added a corresponding route with a catchall

```
routes.MapRoute("reactApp", "react/{*page}", new { controller = "React", action = "Index" });
```

Other than that I've tried to add:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite React links" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="react/*" />
            <conditions />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

to the Web.config file.

I've completly run out of ideas as to fix this.

Comment: What actually happens when you hit refresh or go directly to a url, do you get an error, or a blank page, etc.?

Comment: @chrisbyte get a blank page with 404 the page cannot be found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one that works for me is to add a `NotFound` route to the `global.asax` `Application_Start()`, which redirects to your React app's `index.html`. I do this when using React as the UI/client and a .Net MVC project as the api.

This is the only change I need to make in the backend, I don't do any rewrite rules or extra controllers and it works.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    RouteTable.Routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    // map route for React
    RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("NotFound", "{*url}", "~/index.html");
}
```

For the React side, I also have to make sure the `Router` basename is set to the IIS site, but I also run all my sites under `Default Web Site` due to how our organization hosts our web applications so it may not apply in your situation, but is worth noting. https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string

```
<Router basename='/mysite'>
</Router>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. I've got the whole React app in a Scripts/React folder, since it's an upgrade from the current aspx website, but running them parallell, so that the user can opt out of the new design for the time being.

Comment: Got it to work. Modified your answer so that all incoming urls that originated from the React homepage used the React Controller to load the initial React page.